# issue getting correct output with nested collection

Tags: laravel

Nested:

```
   $collection = collect([
     'result' => [
        ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
        ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
        ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100]
      ],
    ]);

    $filtered = $collection->where('price', 100);

    $filtered->all();
```

Not Nested:

```
  $collection = ([
        ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
        ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
        ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
    ]);

    $filtered = $collection->where('price', 100);

    $filtered->all();
```

**I can get this output when the above is not nested with result, how can i get the same output nested with result?**

```
/*
    [
        ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
    ]
*/
```

Comment: How is the nested form ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that, I added the nested vs not nested sections. Thanks

Comment: The "nested" code you've shared is invalid PHP, can you update the question to include the code you're using so that we can better understand what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated it, I hope that makes a little more sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if you filter on result key of collection

```
$filtered = $collection.result->where('price', 100);
```

Comment: I was hoping it would be that easy! Unfortunately my application doesn't like when I add the ".result" as I get the below error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')'

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do. I just created a new variable:

$collection1 = collect($collection['result']);

which seemed to resolve my issue.